# How can I set a proxy to all the system from a iOS app?

Tags: ios, proxy

The proxy must affect all the system, ideally I would like to do this without on not jailbreaked devices, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible .... You cant do it from an app .... You would have to use some Webservice....

Comment: Are you sure, have you checked iOS6 API?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this from inside an iOS app.

Sorry.

Comment: Are you sure, have you checked iOS6 API?

Comment: Yes. And there are two answers now that both say no. Just because the answer isn't what you want doesn't mean that we should check again :)